# Why reference properties works only through context

Tags: c#, ef-core-2.0

I have two classes Order and OrderDetail:

```
  public class Order : Entity
{
    public Order(KitchenAppContext context) : base(context)
    {

    }
    public Order() : base()
    {

    }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public Guid MenuId { get; set; }
    public virtual Menu Menu { get; set; }
    public bool IsClosed { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public virtual int PeopleCount { get { return Details.Count; } }
    public virtual List<OrderDetail> Details { get; set; } = new List<OrderDetail>();
}

 public class OrderDetail : Entity
{
    public OrderDetail(KitchenAppContext context) : base(context)
    {

    }

    public OrderDetail() : base()
    {

    }
    public Guid UserId { get; set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
    public virtual List<PaymentDetail> Payments { get; set; } = new List<PaymentDetail>();
    public virtual Order Order { get; set; }
    public Guid OrderId { get; set; }
}
```

They are mapped like this:

```
  void OrderMapping(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        var etBuilder = builder.Entity<Order>();
        etBuilder.HasKey(m => new { m.Id });
        etBuilder.HasOne(o => o.Menu).WithMany(a => a.Orders).HasForeignKey(f => f.MenuId);
        etBuilder.HasMany(o => o.Details).WithOne(d => d.Order).HasForeignKey(f => f.OrderId);
    }

  void OrderDetailMapping(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        var etBuilder = builder.Entity<OrderDetail>();
        etBuilder.HasKey(m => new { m.Id });
        etBuilder.HasOne(o => o.User).WithMany(u => u.Details).HasForeignKey(f => f.UserId);
        etBuilder.HasOne(o => o.Order).WithMany(u => u.Details).HasForeignKey(f => f.OrderId);
        etBuilder.HasMany(o => o.Payments).WithOne(d => d.OrderDetail).HasForeignKey(f => f.OrderDetailId);
    }
```

When I create order and order details :

```
  var order = new Order(Context);
        Context.Orders.Add(order);
        var oderDetail = new OrderDetail(Context) { Order = order };
```

Details of order empty there and OrderId of orderdetails is null also. When I add created order detail in context then it will be added to Details and OrderId becomes Id of created order. Why it works only when I add it to context? I want that it works without adding it to context. Maybe, I should do something in consctructor of classes (with Context parameter)? How can I do this?

**EDIT:**
Order and OrderDetails classes inherited from abstact class Entity:

```
 public abstract class Entity
{
    Guid id;
    public Guid Id
    {
        get
        {
            if (id == null || id == Guid.Empty)
            {
                id = Guid.NewGuid();
            }
            return id;
        }
        set
        {
            id = value;
        }
    }

    public Entity(KitchenAppContext context)
    {
        Context = context;
    }

    public Entity()
    {

    }
    public MainContext Context;
}
```

Also, as you see, I have constructor without parameter. I created them because EF shows this message when I'm getting entities from context:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: 'A parameterless constructor was not found on entity type 'Order'. In order to create an instance of 'Order' EF requires that a parameterless constructor be declared.'
```

How can I avoid this error without creating conscrtuctors without parameter?

Comment: `Order` does not appear to have an `Id` property. What do you expect the details of a new Order to contain, you have created it but only set the context?

Comment: @iakobski, Id of entities are in 'Entity' entity. I want that order should have Details and OrderDetails OrderId should be Id of order when I do new OrderDetail(Context) { Order = order }; (without Context.OrderDetails.Add(orderDetail);)

Comment: @DIlshod Please edit your question to include the source code of the `Entity` class or show the documentation/API of that class.

Comment: @DIlshod Why do you want to add a `Context` parameter to all your entities? This sounds like an annoying restriction to always get an active `Context` object from somewhere (static access or method parameter). In fact, entity framework doesn't like that because it wants to create objects when loading data from the database. That's why you get the error message that a parameterless constructor has to be added.

Comment: @Progman, Yes I want to add a Context parameter in my entities. In my app, in all places when I create new entity I'm adding it to Context. I'm getting many exceptions (like null reference exception, square contains no matching element exception when I'm using reference properties) in logic when I create entity without context parameret. Also, manu programmes who are using my code always got this kind of exception. That's why I decided that ALL entities should use one Context. Is it possbile to do structure like this in EF core? I think, I saw this kind of structure somewhere.

Comment: @DIlshod You can use `Context.Add(this);` inside the constructor of your `Entity`class to add the object to the context, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbcontext.add. But this really sound like it doesn't make sense to have such a constructor. The objects coming from the entity framework will not have the `Context` property set (why do you have this property in your `Entity` class anyway). You can add the object that way to your context, but you have to check for yourself if it is useful for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved second issue (`A parameterless constructor was not found...` exception) like this:

1. I setted default constructor of Entity class and sub entities as protected
2. When I load entity from DB Context property of entities will be null, because EF uses default constructor. That's why I created my own IQuerable collection. It sets Context property when it's not setted:

   `class IContextable<T> :` `IQueryable<T>` `where T : Entity`
   {

   ```
   public IQueryable<T> SourceQuery { get; set; }
   public KitchenAppContext Context { get; set; }
   public IContextable(IQueryable<T> query, KitchenAppContext context)
   {
       SourceQuery = query;
       Context = context;
   }

   public Type ElementType => SourceQuery.ElementType;

   public Expression Expression => SourceQuery.Expression;

   public IQueryProvider Provider => SourceQuery.Provider;

   public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
   {
       foreach (var entity in SourceQuery)
       {
           if (entity.Context == null || entity.Context != Context)
               entity.Context = Context;
           yield return entity;
       }
   }

   IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
   {
       return this.GetEnumerator();
   }
   }
   ```

And my GetEntities method in my Context class:

```
public IQueryable<T> GetEntities<T>() where T : Entity
    {
        IQueryable<T> query = Set<T>();
        return new IContextable<T>(query, this);
    }
```

Maybe, there was better ways, but I couldn't found them. It works now, but I'm still waiting for good answer

Answer (score 1):

When you create the `OrderDetail` object you have to do something with it. Currently  you have only set the `Order` property. And that's it, EntityFramework doesn't know that this object exists so it cannot do anything with it.

To make it "known" to EntityFramework you have to add it directly or indirectly to the context. The obvious way is to add the object directly to the context as you have already said and tried:

```
Context.OrderDetails.Add(orderDetail);
```

Another way is it to add the `OrderDetail` object to your `Order` objects `Details` property/list. When the `Order` object is added to the context and it references a `OrderDetail` object, then saving the `Order` object will also "see" the `OrderDetail` object and save it as well. This way the `OrderDetail` object is added *indirectly* to the context. The code might look like this:

```
var order = new Order(Context);
var orderDetail = new OrderDetail(Context)
{
    Order = order // might not be needed
};
order.Details.Add(orderDetail);
Context.Orders.Add(order);
```

This will save the `Order` object. Additionally it will check the references and links and will see the added `OrderDetail` object. So it will save the `OrderDetail` object as well.

Comment: I think, I understood it. What about second problems (cunstructor of entities)? I want to create entity only with Context. Then I think, I will not need do context.Entities.Add(entity). How can I create this structure?

Comment: inside constructor  `context.Add(this)`

Comment: @John, what if I load entity from EF?