# How IQueryable creates instance of entity and how to catch it

Tags: c#, iqueryable, ef-core-2.0

I have my own `IQueryable` class :

```
internal class IContextable<T> : IQueryable<T> where T : Entity
{
    public IQueryable<T> SourceQuery { get; set; }
    public KitchenAppContext Context { get; set; }

    public IContextable(IQueryable<T> query, KitchenAppContext context)
    {
        SourceQuery = query;
        Context = context;
    }

    public Type ElementType => SourceQuery.ElementType;
    public Expression Expression => SourceQuery.Expression;
    public IQueryProvider Provider => SourceQuery.Provider;

    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        foreach (var entity in SourceQuery)
        {
            if (entity.Context == null || entity.Context != Context)
                entity.Context = Context;

            yield return entity;
        }
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return this.GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

I'm using it in loading entities from EF. As you can see, I want to set context of entities (in `GetEnumerator` method).

Here is the `GetEntities` method:

```
public IQueryable<T> GetEntities<T>() where T : Entity
{
    IQueryable<T> query = Set<T>();
    return new IContextable<T>(query, this);
}
```

It works when I do

```
var users = Context.GetEntities<User>().ToList();
```

It sets context of entities. But when I do

```
var users = Context.GetEntities<User>().Single();
```

`GetEnumerator` will not work and context will be null (same with `FirstOrDefault`, `First`, ...). I want just set context of entity when entity loads from database. I can not use `.ToList()` in `GetEntities` method, because it will be performance problem. How can I do this? Is there any better solution for this case?

Comment: IQueryable doesn't create anything, it's just a query. It's the LINQ provider, in this case EF Core, that converts the query to something that can run, executes that and produces the results

Comment: What are you trying to do and why? Most likely it can be done without trying to replace IQueryable. [Global query filters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/filters) for example can be used to modify queries

Comment: `Single()` returns a single item, not an `IEnumerable` which is why you cannot iterate over it. It's unclear what you are asking here.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, As I said in question, I just want to set Context property of entities when I load them from DB

Comment: @DIlshod that's what you assume the solution is. What is the *actual* problem? Why do you want to add that property to all entities and what does it contain? Is that data that comes from the database itself?

Comment: Oh, I didn't even notice you were trying to assign a `DbContext` property to every entity, that's, er.... horrible!

Comment: @DIlshod and yes, trying to tie an Entity with **and already disposed context** is a bad idea that violates the very essence of an ORM - separating the entities from the database infrastructure. If you try to turn those entities into ActiveRecords, don't. ORMs *replace* activerecords

Comment: It is from my last question. Reason is there: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56179785/why-reference-properties-works-only-through-context

Comment: @Dllshod that link doesn't explain anything. It's the same thing you ask here - how to store a context inside an entity, which is a bad idea. You don't need to inherit from `Entity` whatever it is.

Comment: @DIlshod you should take a look at [this page](http://xyproblem.info/). You trying to implement a solution, not fix a problem. You need to step back and give us a functional example of what issue you actually ran into. A snippet of code that causes the same problem that we can run and test. Then we can provide you with a GOOD answer.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, Why it is bad idea? And Why I shouldn't inherit them from Entity class?

Comment: @DIlshod you have a lot of people telling you that what you are trying to do is wrong. Why ask for help if you won't accept it?

Comment: EF Core 2.1 supports [Injecting services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/constructors#injecting-services) (including `DbContext`) via entity constructor out of the box.

Comment: @Marie, It is wrong!!! And this is everything? I didn't get any good solution

Comment: @DIlshod I already gave you the solution. The link contains an example with `Blog` entity having `BloggingContext` injected by EF Core. Forget about custom `IQueryable` - first, it requires also a custom `IQueryProvider`, and second it breaks many EF Core features like `Async` methods, `Include` / `ThenInclude` etc. So use the out of the box functionality (upgrade to v2.1+ if needed).